# ProgressBar progress change with all files that need to be downloaded

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, webclient, download

I'm making a WPF application where I use WebClient to download files form a webserver. I have a list of URL's with all the files i have to download. I use a foreach to loop through every URL and download each one at the time. The first URL much be completed before moving to the next one. I know the size of each file. Is there a way where I can set my e.ProgressPercentage to know the size of all files instead of loading from 0 to 100% for each file. I know that I'm calling DownloadProtocol for each URL right now, which makes a new instance of WebClient, but it is the only way I can think of to fulfill my solution, which is to download one file at a time.

```
public DownloadStart()
{
    foreach(var url in ListOfDownloadURL)
    {
       DownloadGameFile dlg = new DownloadGameFile();
       await dlg.DownloadProtocol(url, myLocation);
    }
}
```

---

Download function in DownloadGameFile class:

```
public async Task DownloadProtocol(string address, string location)
{

    Uri Uri = new Uri(address);
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        //client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        //client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgress);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage);
            //ProgressBar = e.ProgressPercentage (total)
        };

        client.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Cancelled == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Download has been canceled.");
            }
            else
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");
            }

        };

        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(Uri, location);
    }

}
```

Comment: Any reason to not download files simultaneously?

Comment: Well it is because i want to continue from the last file that was in progress. When I close down the application and start it up again i want to download from the last file that was in progress last time I used the application. When i start up the application i check all the files that have been download and if those files that have been downloaded is the right size I skip them until I reach a file which size is below the actual, then i delete this file and start over again with this current file. That's my solution for resume a download for now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the easy way out and just update the progress when file is completed? Something like...

```
ProgressBar p = new ProgressBar();
p.Maximum = ListOfDownloadURL.Count();

foreach(var url in ListOfDownloadURL)
{
   DownloadGameFile dlg = new DownloadGameFile();
   await dlg.DownloadProtocol(url, myLocation);
   p.Value += 1;
}
```

Or if you insist, you could query file sizes before you begin downloading, sum total bytes of all the files and then calculate the percentage when ever `DownloadProgressChanged` is fired.

```
var bytes = Convert.ToInt64(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Length"]);
```

Comment: lets say i want to download 5 files each file have a size about 5bytes. Then i want the progress bar to go from 0 to 100% when alle the file is download which will be 5*5bytes in total.

Comment: Edited, hope it helps.

Comment: I really appreciate you are trying to help @MikkoViitala. Can you come with an example with my DownloadProtocol function? - thank you. I have a variable called TotalBytes = xxxxxxx;

Comment: No, I can point you to right direction but not write the complete code.